# Return of the valid view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method like this one:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.MyViewModel viewModel)
  {
     // Code here to handle the save to the database and in the case 
         // where some validation are not accepted, return View(viewModel)

     return View("Index", viewModel);
  }
```

When I run this code and my viewModel is valid, I would like to return the user to the view with the list of items.

I know that I must use the RedirectToAction("Index") in this case instead of the last line but I wonder to know why when I run this code and the last line is executed, MVC returns the Edit page instead of the List page.

And for which reasons would I specify a view name in the parameters list of the View function if I'm not able to specify other than the view handled by the controller?

Thank you.

Comment: After searching for a while, I finally found that the problem is just that I send the wrong viewmodel to the Index page because this page receive a strongly typed list of viewmodel. In this case, I searched with the help HttpFox add-on for Firefox for the difference between a simple return View("Index") and a RedirectToAction("Index") and the last one is definitively the best choice in all points. First, it send an http status code 302 which is best to be compliant with PRG pattern and second, I don't have to duplicate the logic of my Index action to fill the list of viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that I must use the RedirectToAction("Index") in this case
>   instead of the last line but I wonder to know why when I run this code
>   and the last line is executed, MVC returns the Edit page instead of
>   the List page.

The `Edit` view is not executed. It is the `Index` view to which you have passed an instance of `MyViewModel` even if in the browser address bar you are seeing `/somecontroller/edit`.